# jquery callback function scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, callback

when i use jquery to create an element(a div, for example) in a callback function, it doesn't allow me to manipulate the newly created element outside the callback function, how can I get around this?

here is the example:

```
$.get('menu.xml',function(data){

//create a new element with an ID called "#newElement"

})

//I can't select the element outside the callback function so the following code dosen't work:

$('#newElement').css('background','black');
```

Comment: thanks for the answers, you guys answers the questions in a clear and nice way, I hope someday I can contribute a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can** select it outside, but not *yet*, that `$.get()` callback takes some time to run (it has to get the data from the server, the callback happens *later*, when that finishes), so when you do this:

```
$('#newElement').css('background','black');
```

That element isn't there *yet* (and so the selector doesn't find anything...it's running *before* that callback creating it does), you need to wait until the callback finishes before continuing any code that needs elements created by it.  Like this:

```
$.get('menu.xml',function(data){
  //create a new element with an ID called "#newElement"
  //kick off stuff that uses "#newElement"
  $('#newElement').css('background','black'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get('menu.xml',function(data){
     //create a new element with an ID called ".newElement"

     $('<div/>').val(data).attr('id','newElement').css('background','black').append('#container');

})
```

Try modifying the element within the callback, also try using the class instead of the id

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the code you've shown, it seems your trying to manipulate '#newElement' before it exists. The reason for that is '#newElement' is created in the callback of '$.get'.

Its important to remember that asynchronous functions in javascript don't cause the thread to wait, this is why callbacks exist. So, before your callback function for '$.get' has even been executed, you are trying to manipulate '#newElement'.

For instance, if you adjust your code to:

```
$.get('menu.xml',function(data){

    //create a new element with an ID called "#newElement"
    ....

    $('#newElement').css('background','black');
})
```

You will find that it works.